# StringTokenizer to Scala Iterator

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert `java.util.StringTokenizer` to Scala's `Iterator` and the following approach fails:

```
def toIterator(st: StringTokenizer): Iterator[String] =
   Iterator.continually(st.nextToken()).takeWhile(_ => st.hasMoreTokens()))
```

But this works:

```
def toIterator(st: StringTokenizer): Iterator[String] =
    Iterator.fill(st.countTokens())(st.nextToken())
```

You can see this in Scala console:

```
scala> Iterator("a b", "c d").map(new java.util.StringTokenizer(_)).flatMap(st => Iterator.continually(st.nextToken()).takeWhile(_ => st.hasMoreTokens())).toList
res1: List[String] = List(a, c)

scala> Iterator("a b", "c d").map(new java.util.StringTokenizer(_)).flatMap(st => Iterator.fill(st.countTokens())(st.nextToken())).toList
res2: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d)
```

As you can see `res1` is incorrect and `res2` is correct. What am I doing wrong? The first version should work and is preferred since it is 2x faster than second approach since it does not scan the string twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`takeWhile` is not intended to be used statefully. It should take a pure function that determines, solely based on the *input*, whether or not to continue.

Specifically, the iterator must *produce* the value *before* the `takeWhile` predicate gets called. Even though your function ignores the `takeWhile` argument, it still gets evaluated. So `nextToken` gets called and *then* we check for more tokens.

To be perfectly precise, in your `"a b"` case,

1. First, we call `nextToken`, which is what `Iterator.continually` does. There's a next token, so it returns `"a"`.
2. Now, to determine if we should *include* the next token, we call your predicate with `"a"` as argument. Your predicate ignores `"a"` and calls `hasMoreTokens`. Our tokenizer has more tokens (namely, `"b"`), so it returns true. Continue.
3. Now we call `nextToken` again. This returns `"b"`.
4. We need to determine if we should include this in our result, so our `takeWhile` predicate runs with `"b"` as argument. Our `takeWhile` predicate ignores its argument and calls `hasMoreTokens`. We have no more tokens anymore, so this returns `false`. We should not include this element.
5. `takeWhile` has returned false, so we stop at the last element for which it returned true. Our resulting list is `List("a")`.

Since we're abusing a pure functional technique like `takeWhile` to be stateful, we get unintuitive results.

As much as it looks snazzy and clever to have a one-line solution, what you have is a stateful, imperative object that you want to adapt to the `Iterator` interface. Hiding that statefulness in a bunch of pure function calls is not a good idea, so we should just write our own subclass of `Iterator` and do it properly.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer

final class StringTokenizerIterator(
  private val tokenizer: StringTokenizer
) extends Iterator[String] {

  def hasNext: Boolean = tokenizer.hasMoreTokens

  def next(): String = tokenizer.nextToken()

}

object Example {

  def toIterator(st: StringTokenizer): Iterator[String] =
    new StringTokenizerIterator(st)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(Iterator("a b", "c d")
            .map(new java.util.StringTokenizer(_))
            .flatMap(toIterator(_))
            .toList)
  }

}
```

We're doing the same work you were doing calling the appropriate `StringTokenizer` functions, but we're doing it in a full class that *encapsulates* the state, rather than pretending the stateful part is not there. It's longer code, yes, but it *should* be longer. We don't want the messy parts of it to go unnoticed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The encapsulation approach is indeed better and I now understand the problem with the `takeWhile(f)` approach. It essentially is like a `do yield next() while f` instead of `while(f) yield x`.

Comment: @pathikrit Sort of. It's more like (sorry, can't do newlines in comments) `do tmp = next(); break unless f(tmp); yield tmp while true`. The `break` happens *after* getting the next element of the inner iterator but before yielding it from the outer one.

Comment: It would be nice to have a `span` or `takeUntil` util in Iterator which would work in this case (again, the encapsulation is better but just as an excercise)